# Why does android studio gives warning on variable not used even when I have clearly used it in

Tags: android-studio, flutter, error-handling, warnings

I have need annoyed with the warning from the `android studio` on me not using the defined `variable` but in actual I have used it. What can be issue ? is something wrong with my coding pattern ?

```
class CategoryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<CategoryModel> _categories = [];
  int _currenPage = 1;
  int _lastPage = 1;
  int _perPage = 1;

  List<CategoryModel> getCategories() => [..._categories];

  void setCategories(List<CategoryModel> _records) {
    _categories = _records;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future fetchCategories() async {
    try {
      ApiCall().getData(categoriesApi).then((data) {
        if (data['status'] == 'success') {
          _currenPage = data['collection']['current_page'];
```

In the above code, we can clearly see that the `_current_page` is been `defined` and `used` in the `fetchCategories` function. then why is `android studio` `crying` for the same?

Above is just an example and many more such `variable` exist and I have issued `warnings` for all.

Any suggestions on how to solve this ?

Comment: You are declaring the variable and you are assigning values to it, but then you don't appear to use it / do anything with it. It may as well never have been declared - if you deleted its declaration and all assignments you make to it, your code would still work.

Answer (score 1):

```
_currenPage = data['collection']['current_page'];
```

This means that you are declaring the `_currenPage` variable you haven't used it anywhere.
you can use it like `print(_currenPage)` or pass it in some function.
hopes it helps!